# Python User defined number of output decimals

Tags: python, format, output, significant-digits

I want to make a small python script to calculate pi to N number of decimal points and then only output that number of decimals. I don't know how to change the print statement to dynamically limit the number of outputted decimals. Here's my code.

```
#!python
import math

N = input("Enter the number of digits of pi you would like to compute: ")

runs = math.ceil(N/math.log(2))

a_0 = 1.0
b_0 = 1.0/(2.0**(1.0/2.0))
t_0 = 1.0/4.0
p_0 = 1.0

for x in xrange(1,N):

    a = (a_0 + b_0)/2
    b = (a_0*b_0)**(1.0/2.0)
    t = t_0 - p_0*(a_0 - a)**2
    p = 2*p_0

    pi = ((a_0 + b_0)**2)/(4*t)
    print pi

    a_0 = a
    b_0 = b
    t_0 = t
    p_0 = p

print 'Pi to %d number of digits is: ' % (N)
print "%0" N "d\n" % pi
```

I know my last *`print` statement* isn't how you implement this feature, but it gives an idea of how you might do it in something kinda like **`C`**.

I just want that last print statement to output **`pi`** to **`N`** *number of digits*.

Comment: How about `"%%.%df" % N % pi`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!